# $a,b,c\in Z, (x,y) \in Z$ is a solution of $ax+by=c$, proof that c is divisible by $\gcd(a,b)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

let $a,b,c\in Z$ and $(x,y) \in Z$ is a solution of $ax+by=c$, prove that $c$ is divisible by $\gcd(a,b)$.

All hints are welcome, I need a point where I can start from.

Comment: Both $ax$ and $by$ are divisible by it.

Comment: thanks, how can I write that in correct formal speech?
ax|gcd(a,b) and by|gcd(a,b)
so 
ax+by must be | gcd(a,b)

Comment: I do not know how you can do that; I did so in my comment.

Comment: Yes, you did good

Comment: You can write that $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $ax$. If you use $\mid$, this is written $\gcd(a,b)\mid ax$.

Comment: Your claim is not true for $x,y\in\mathbb R$. However, it *is* true for $x,y\in\mathbb Z$. This is likely what you meant and so it should be added to the question.

Comment: @SuperNova By definition the gcd of $\,a,b\,$ is a *common* divisor of $\,a,b,\,$ i.e. $\,d = \gcd(a,b)\mid a,b,\,$ so $\,d\mid ax,by,\,$ so it divides their sum. In other words, the multiples of $\,d\,$ are closed under addition, and by multiplication by arbitrary integers (i.e. they form an ideal).

Answer (score 0):

As a few commentors have pointed out, this proof is quite straightfoward. Clearly, $\gcd(a,b) \mid ax$ and $\gcd(a,b) \mid by$. Thus, $\gcd(a,b) \mid (ax+by)$. Because $ax + by = c$, we also know that $\gcd(a,b) \mid c$, and we are done.